# paypal unsupported currency and fees php

Tags: php, paypal

Hi i work on paypal integration on php site and I need  to convert SAR (Saudi Arabian Riyal) to USD, but paypal fees pay seller

E.x 1 USD = 3.75 SAR

I use this code for convert to usd and work correct:

```
<?php
$sar = 3.75;
$amount = $total / $sar;
```

And this work great.
So i have product cost 10 SAR in paypal give me $2.67, but from bayer card get 10.38 SAR.

I want to fees (0.38 SAR) pay seller. From bayer's account get just 10 SAR...

Any idea how to make this?
All paypal fees are fixed?

Thanks

Comment: PayPal fees change depending on your income level. It's all in the PayPal docs